# Nodejs how to module.exports after a function is being called

Tags: node.js

I'm building a REST API application with nodejs,
I'm also building an external package to that application.
That package is adapter between the REST API to the database.

The package `index.js` is this:

```
db = undefined;
var User = require('./models/user/user-model');

var neo4j = require('seraph');
module.exports.connect = function (url, username, password) {
  db = neo4j({server: url, user: username, pass: password});
};
module.exports.User = User;
```

Now there are few problems for me here:

1. In the `User` module is depends on the `db` object to be instantiated, but because I actually loads the module before the method `connect` is being invoked the `db` object is undefined, I can solve it by moving the `require('User');` to inside the connect method and it works, but from what I know loading module inside a function is not a good idea.
   How can I be sure to load the module after the `db` object is instantiated?
2. Is that the proper way to share variable between modules? I want the `db` to be available in every module in the package.. How I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I would define db in a separate file. And require that file once in the main app file.

The main problem is how to make sure that connection is established before any query goes out.

example:

db.js

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
  db = neo4j({server: url, user: username, pass: password}, callback);
}
```

server.js

```
var db = require('./db');
db(function(err, graph){
  if (err) throw err;
  //here start up the server
});
```

Comment: Wrapping my application in a function is not something I wanna do.. and It doesn't solve the problem of requiring inside a function